# How can I catch any change in a QListWidget?

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt4, qlistwidget

I've created a QListWidget that drives the visibility of different QGroupBoxes. From a UX point of view, selecting an item in the list let's them see different user settings (the user settings are in the different QGroupBoxes). The title of the Group Box matches the item.text() to help improve the clarity of the UI.

There are essentially 2 things I need to do to make this work:

1. Set Group Box visibility based on list selection
2. Set Group Box titles based on list item text.

Currently I have it working well when you click on the list items with your mouse. However, if a user changes the name of an item and hits enter, the name of Group Boxes is not updating until I click my mouse again. In addition, if I use the up/down arrow keys to change selection, the Group Box visibility settings are also not updating properly until I click my mouse.

I can see the problem below but I have not found a way to connect all updates. So... any thoughts on how to connect my code to mouse clicks, the enter key, and the arrow keys? Basically any time the listWidget updates? Many thanks.

First create a *.ui file using this...

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ui version="4.0">
 <class>Form</class>
 <widget class="QWidget" name="Form">
  <property name="geometry">
   <rect>
    <x>0</x>
    <y>0</y>
    <width>400</width>
    <height>300</height>
   </rect>
  </property>
  <property name="windowTitle">
   <string>Form</string>
  </property>
  <widget class="QListWidget" name="listWidget">
   <property name="geometry">
    <rect>
     <x>20</x>
     <y>50</y>
     <width>91</width>
     <height>192</height>
    </rect>
   </property>
   <property name="alternatingRowColors">
    <bool>true</bool>
   </property>
   <property name="currentRow">
    <number>-1</number>
   </property>
   <item>
    <property name="text">
     <string>row 0</string>
    </property>
    <property name="checkState">
     <enum>Checked</enum>
    </property>
    <property name="flags">
     <set>ItemIsSelectable|ItemIsEditable|ItemIsDragEnabled|ItemIsUserCheckable|ItemIsEnabled</set>
    </property>
   </item>
```

Then update the path to your *.ui file in the code below.

```
#! /usr/bin/env python

import sys, functools
from PyQt4 import QtGui, uic

def listWidgetControls(setControls):
    print setControls

myApp = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
myWindow = uic.loadUi("\\\\path\\to\\file.ui")
myWindow.show()

setControls = functools.partial(listWidgetControls,myWindow)
myWindow.listWidget.clicked.connect(setControls)

myApp.exec_()
```

Comment: please provide a [mre]

Comment: In order to give a completely reproducible example I would need to upload a *.ui file. I'm new to this site. How could I share that file? 
Thank you.

Comment: the .ui is an XML file so open it with an editor and copy the content in your post

Comment: I updated the original post. Does that give you what you need to test? Thank you.

Comment: Nevermind. I solved it by replacing the clicked.connect line with

myWindow.listWidget.currentRowChanged.connect(setControls)
myWindow.listWidget.itemChanged.connect(setControls)